The ARXIV library in Python does not give me the latest articles until I update the library
I am using the python arxiv library to obtain the most recent AI article, the problem is that it does not give me the most recent article until I update the library every time I need the most recent article, what solution could I try? The problem is that this will be executed on a server and I cannot turn off the server daily to update the library.
import arxiv

client = arxiv.Client()

# Search for the most recent article in cs.AI
search = arxiv.Search(
    query="cat:cs.AI",
    max_results=1,
    sort_by=arxiv.SortCriterion.SubmittedDate,
    sort_order=arxiv.SortOrder.Descending
)

# Get the first (most recent) result
result = next(client.results(search))

I tried making a request several times in one day and they always gave me the same article even if it wasn't the most recent until I updated the library.
I know I could use the API directly but I prefer to use the library, I found similar answers but only with the API
